# Error with overload operator>>

Tags: c++, inheritance, raw-pointer

Trying to use `operator>>` for my class plane, and I have an error in my `main()`. It says that

```
"no operator ">>" matches these operands    Air.
operand types are: std::istream >> Aircraft *"
```

my main():

```
int main()
{
    Aircraft* air[2];
    int choice;
    std::cout << "Plane '1' and Helicopter '2'" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> choice; 
    if (choice == 1)
    {
        Plane p;
        air[0] = new Plane;
        std::cin >> air[0]; //HERE IS AN ERROR
        air[0]->ShowTabl();
        std::cout << air[0];
    }
    /*if (choice == 2)
    {
        //air[1] = new Helicopter;
        //TODO: << and >>  
    }*/
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

My read():

```
std::istream& Aircraft::read(std::istream& frFile)
{
    std::cout << "Name: ";
    frFile >> Name;
    std::cout << "Weight: ";
    frFile >> weight;
    return frFile;
}
```

Operator `>>`:

it is in (.h):

> friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, Aircraft& A);

it is in (.cpp):

```
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is,  Aircraft& A)
{   
    return A.read(is);
}
```

As for using in a way , like this ,so it is perfect:

```
Plane p;
    air[0] = new Plane;
    std::cin >> p; // it's okay
```

What do I do wrong with this?

Comment: The compiler told you you're giving a pointer and your overload expects a reference.

Comment: You are declaring an array of *pointers* to `Aircraft`.  Do you really need to use pointers?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I expect so, given that this is an inheritance-related question. See how the array is of `Aircraft*`s but can contain `Plane*`s or (once uncommented) `Helicopter*`s.  As I said in my answer, I am less sure about the need for an array, though.

Comment: Why the downvotes on [@Roberto’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43097448/27302) and [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43098041/27302)? The only reason I can think of is that using raw pointers in C++ is rarely a good idea and somebody thinks @Nikitax shouldn’t use them, but as I explain in my answer I think they’re necessary now, and even if they’re not the answers are better than no solution at all.

Comment: Oh, and this isn’t directly related to the question, but be sure to `delete` whichever pointer you `new` in the if statement (to be safe, initialize both to `nullptr` and you can then you can `delete` both even without a corresponding `new`), and make sure the destructors are virtual so the right one is called.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Throughout this answer I assume that both `Helicopter` and `Plane` publicly inherit from `Aircraft`. If they don’t, the explanation is still correct but the rest of the advice is probably wrong.

The line

```
Aircraft* air[2];
```

declares `air` as an array of two pointers to `Aircraft`.¹ You probably do want the pointers, despite some of the other comments, because you seem to be working with inheritance so you can’t just use `Aircraft` directly. So far you only ever have one of them, so I’m less sure that you need an array, but that may be useful later.

Because `air` contains pointers to `Aircraft` instead of directly containing `Aircraft`, you need to deal with the pointed-to objects at the extra level of indirection. Your stream extraction operator (`operator>>`) is for an `Aircraft`, not for an `Aircraft*`, so if you want to use it with the `Plane` you allocated on line 10 of your `main` function, you need to extracted it to the pointed-to `Aircraft`, `*air[0]`, instead of the pointer, `air[0]`.

I am not sure how well the `Aircraft::read` method could work when it isn’t `virtual` (I would expect you’d also want to read in a `Plane`-specific property like `wingspan`), but perhaps you plan to implement that later once you have this part working, which is sensible.

¹ You can see this by reading the type from the variable name outward, going to the right before the left. Thus, you see `air`, go to the right to see `[2]` meaning “array of two”, followed by `*` meaning “pointer to”, followed by `Aircraft`. Knowing this rule helps a lot when you have more complicated types, like functions that accept arrays.